# Auto-Refresh Report Charts on Visualforce Page

Tags: analytics

I've created a VF page in order to show a couple of Report Charts using information from related Records. Everything displays as expected on my simple little page. The last piece of this puzzle is to get the charts to automatically refresh when the record is re-loaded. Any help you can offer would be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Ben

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="NPS_Survey__c" extensions="NPSSurveyController">
<base target="_top" />
   <apex:form >
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>     
               <td><strong>Follow-Ups by Type</strong></td>    
               <td><strong>Follow-Ups | No Answer</strong></td>                                                      
              </tr>  
            <tr>
               <td>
<analytics:reportChart reportId="00O13000008TyVK" size="small" showRefreshButton="true" filter="{column:'NPS_Follow_Up__c.Survey_ID__c', operator:'equals', value:'{!Id}'}" hideOnError="false" > </analytics:reportChart>
               </td>    
               <td>
<analytics:reportChart reportId="00O13000008TyVP" size="small"  showRefreshButton="true" filter="{column:'NPS_Follow_Up__c.Survey_ID__c', operator:'equals', value:'{!Id}'}" hideOnError="false" > </analytics:reportChart>
               </td>                                                    
              </tr>                      
              </table>         
</apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I think I got it. Adding cacheResults="false"  makes the Report Charts refresh everytime the page is loaded. Not inserting it will require you to manually refresh the charts each time you'd like them updated.

Comment: Ben post that as an answer .

Answer (score 2):

I think I got it. Adding cacheResults="false" (as shown below) makes the Report Charts refresh everytime the page is loaded. Not inserting it will require you to manually refresh the charts each time you'd like them updated